# postgresql psql command \d does not list indexes

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I created a table in PGSQL (version 13) using the following command:

```
db1=# create table temp2(
foo int PRIMARY KEY,
bar varchar(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE
```

The `\d` or `d+` command does not list the associated indexes for the table (contrary to what I gathered from reading various sites.)

```
db1=# \d temp2
 foo    | integer               |           | not null |
 bar    | character varying(20) |           | not null |

db1=# \d+ temp2
 foo    | integer               |           | not null |         | plain    |              |
 bar    | character varying(20) |           | not null |         | extended |              |
```

Is there a way I get list indexes associated with a table?

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Comment: Works for me. What version of `psql` are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `tuples_only` set to `on`.

```
 create table temp2(
foo int PRIMARY KEY,
bar varchar(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

test(5432)=# \d temp2
                      Table "public.temp2"
 Column |         Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 foo    | integer               |           | not null | 
 bar    | character varying(20) |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "temp2_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (foo)
    "temp2_bar_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (bar)

test(5432)=# \pset tuples_only on


test(5432)=# \d temp2
 foo    | integer               |           | not null | 
 bar    | character varying(20) |           | not null | 

test(5432)=# \pset tuples_only off
test(5432)=# \d temp2
                      Table "public.temp2"
 Column |         Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 foo    | integer               |           | not null | 
 bar    | character varying(20) |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "temp2_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (foo)
    "temp2_bar_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (bar)
```

Verify by doing:

```
\pset
border                   1
columns                  0
csv_fieldsep             ','
expanded                 off
fieldsep                 '|'
fieldsep_zero            off
footer                   on
format                   aligned
linestyle                ascii
null                     'NULL'
numericlocale            off
pager                    1
pager_min_lines          0
recordsep                '\n'
recordsep_zero           off
tableattr                
title                    
tuples_only              on
unicode_border_linestyle single
unicode_column_linestyle single
unicode_header_linestyle single
```

Comment: Nicely spotted. I couldn't figure out how you could lose half of your \d output

Comment: @Adrian Klaver Thank you very much, that was exactly it.

Comment: Anyone knows where we can put the config into a user HOME?  Somehow, my previous version by default shows the full info with the slash d command. Now it is tuples_only.

Comment: @KeminZhou.  In [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) read the section under *Files*

Answer (score -1):

You need \di to get the index information. Check the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/app-psql.html):

> the letters E, i, m, s, t, and v stand for foreign table, index,
> materialized view, sequence, table, and view, respectively.

Comment: Incorrect answer. `\di` is how you get all indexes in the databases. `\d(+)` will return the index(es) on  the provided table. There is something else wrong in the OP's case.